# Apache syntax problem with listen to localhost

Tags: xubuntu, apache2

Apache sometimes can't read the syntax in my config file. I then get an syntax error for the line with

```
listen localhost
```

or even for

```
listen localhost:80
```

But it's really sporadic that I get this error, after rebooting it sometimes work again, or it does not. Anyway, this line should not throw an syntax error!

I am working with apache 2.4.18 on Xubuntu 16.04

Comment: please show your config file, and remove or obfuscate any vital information before posting.

Answer (score 0):

The [Listen](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) directive requires a port number which instructs Apache to listen to.

Examples:

```
# Listen to incoming connection from anywhere on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen to incoming connection originating
# from the local machine only on port 808-
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080

# The following won't work as there isn't any port number specified
Listen 127.0.0.1
```

On a side note; Although it may work, using hostnames instead of IPs with the [Listen directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) is not documented. So I'd recommend switching `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: actually I tried both of it, listen localhost:80 and listen localhost (updated my question)

Comment: Can you edit your question with more details from the error log in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`? also have you tried replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`?